# C++ why isn't this code writing to file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm having trouble trying to replace text in a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>   
void Place(string& seek)
{
    fstream myfile;
    string holder = "";
    myfile.open("testfile.txt");
    while (seek != holder)
    {
        myfile >> holder;
    }
    myfile << "300";

    myfile.close();
}
```

Using this I am able to read the line I'm trying to change but it does not work for writing.

```
string Pull(string& seek)
{
    fstream myfile;
    string holder = "";
    myfile.open("test.txt");

    while (seek != holder)
    {
        myfile >> holder;
    }
    myfile >> holder;
    myfile.close();
    return holder;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overwriting some text in a file using fstream and delete the rest of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112026/overwriting-some-text-in-a-file-using-fstream-and-delete-the-rest-of-the-file)

Comment: `myfile >> holder;` writes an empty string to the file.

Comment: no that wrights the selection from the file into holder. its used to move through the file and in the second example pull information from it. currently if I try to wright anything after the while loop it does not wright. does the while loop interfere somehow?